# How to avoid or rename key and entry tag in jaxb?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Hi I  am currently using jaxb to get my model saved to xml .  My model I have one string and one hashmap. So  the problem here is while exporting the hashmap to xml  i am getting something like this .

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<customer>
    <addressMap>
        <entry>
            <key>col2</key>
            <value>data2</value>
        </entry>
        <entry>
            <key>col1</key>
            <value>data1</value>
        </entry>
    </addressMap>
</customer>
```

SO here i donot want this entry tag and key instead of that something like below xml I expect..

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<customer>
    <addressMap>
        <col2>data2</col2>         
        <col1>data1</col1>
    </addressMap>
</customer>
```

Is it possible to achieve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost. I would like to suggest a change to the xml-format. Using element names like col1, col2, etc is a "bad" idea. It's not well structured. If you can accept the following format of the xml data I can give you an example on how:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<customer>
    <addressMap>
       <col key="col2">data2</col>
       <col key="col1">data1</col>
    </addressMap>
</customer>
```

I guess you had a class defined something like this:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Customer {
    @XmlElement
    public Map<String,String> addressMap;
}
```

When marshaled with JAXB it should produce your first output. Change it to the following and add the necessary classes:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Customer {
    @XmlElement
    public AddressMap addressMap;
}

public class AddressMap {
    @XmlElement
    public List<Column> col;
}

public class Column {
    @XmlAttribute
    public String key;
    @XmlValue
    public String value;
}
```

Fill it with your data and marshal it and the output should look like my xml example.

**EDIT**:

Keeping `addressMap` as a `HashMap`:

Make `Customer` class look like this:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Customer {
    @XmlElement
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(MapAdapter.class)
    public Map<String,String> addressMap;
}
```

and create the class `MapAdapter`:

```
public class MapAdapter extends XmlAdapter<AddressMap, Map<String,String>> {

    @Override
    public AddressMap marshal(Map<String,String> map) throws Exception {
        AddressMap myMap = new AddressMap();
        myMap.col = new ArrayList<Column>();
        for (Entry<String,String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            Column col = new Column();
            col.key = entry.getKey();
            col.value = entry.getValue();
            myMap.col.add(col);
        }
        return myMap;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String,String> unmarshal(AddressMap myMap) throws Exception {
        Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        for (Column col : myMap.col) {
            map.put(col.key, col.value);
        }
        return map;
    }
}
```

Keep classes `AddressMap` and `Column` as is.

Comment: i agree that my xml format is bad but i can not change the hashmap to list

Comment: @Rajesh: I've updated my answer. It has been put together rather quick, so it can possibly be slimmed a little.

Comment: I am accepting your answer Thanks once again for the rescue